# Не работает запись строк по указателю в цикле

Tags: c++, c

В программе считывается строка и кладется в динамический буфер, пока не будет подан символ \n.
Но при работе цикла происходит одно считывание. Очистка stdin не помогает. Как можно исправить программу, чтобы можно было вводить символы в буфер до подачи \n?
Компилятор g++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* Input(int *length)
{
    int capacity = 200;
    int counter = 0;
    *length = 0;
    char* buffer = (char *) calloc(capacity, sizeof(char));

    while( scanf("%200[^\n]%n", buffer + *length, &counter) != 0)
    { 
        fflush(stdin);
        *length += counter;
        if ( *length > capacity/2 )
        {
            capacity *= 2;
            buffer = (char*) realloc(buffer, capacity * sizeof(char) );
        }

    }
    *(buffer + *length) = '\0';
    return buffer;

}

int main()
{
    int string_length = 0;
    char *str = NULL;

    str = Input(&string_length); 
    printf("String: %s, length: %d\n", str, string_length);
    
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Проще всего эта задача решается чтнием через getchar() (по одному символу) и анализом на '\n'

Comment: Необходимо сделать scanf или fgets

Comment: Ну, если у вас такое учебное задание..., то `\n`, не введенный scanf-ом, придется вычитывать из потока `scanf("%c", ...)`, поскольку fflush(stdin) реально не работает  (но вообще, это какое-то извращение и очевидная глупость)

Comment: Придется по одному символу вводить строку?

Comment: На практике это проще всего. Если вообще реальная задача, то используйте GNU [getline()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)

Comment: А как это поможет в данной задаче? В цикле будет работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если ты считываешь всё кроме `\n`, то в буфере останется этот `\n`. Надо бы дочитать через `getchar()` или `scanf("%*1[\n]")`.
2. В описании scanf говорится:

   > If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.

   В твоём коде получается, что если файл не заканчивается переводом строки, то цикл становится бесконечным. Вероятно, вместо `!=0` стоит использовать `==2`.

   А вообще, лично я в таких случаях использовал вообще другой подход:

   ```
   while(counter = 0, scanf("%200[^\n]%n", buffer + *length, &counter), counter)
   ```

   кстати, если тут Си++, то можно

   ```
   while(scanf("%200[^\n]%n", buffer + *length, &(counter=0)), counter)
   ```

   Думаю, подход с возвращаемым значением формально правильнее, но про этот я точно помню, что он работал.
3. `fflush(stdin)` - штука довольно бесполезная.
4. Проверок на нехватку памяти нет, но вряд ли это имеет отношение к вопросу.

Это всё, что я могу сказать не запуская код.